# Organisation of routes in Rails -- restful_authentication, session and /login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am struggling with the route setup for a Rails application. I have installed restful_authentication and mostly followed the instructions. I have set up the routes this way:

```
map.login '/login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'
map.resource :session
```

If you're not logged in, you're redirected to http://localhost:3000/session/new.
It  makes some kind of sense, as the code in lib/authenticated_system.rb says `redirect_to new_session_path`.

But I thought the routes mapping was supposed to work both ways (code to URL and URL to code). Can someone explain? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map.resource :session` creates a few named resources for you including `new_session_path` (see [ActionController::Resources](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000697)).

`map.login` and `map.logout` are just helper routes to make your code easier to understand. `map.login` (which generates `login_path`) points to the same controller/action combo as `new_session_path` does, it's just easier to remember at a glance what it does.

Comment: I understand map.login does not create new_session_path (I understood this, as my code blew up) but login_path. I'll replace new_session_path with login_path in the lib. Thanks.